# Is there an easy way to phase between different shadertoy shaders in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm looking for a way to switch between multiple shaders that are shaders from shadertoy.com 
I have been using these instructions on how to port [shadertoys with p5.js](https://itp-xstory.github.io/p5js-shaders/#/./docs/examples/shadertoy?id=porting-shadertoy-code-to-p5js-shaders) and have been successful with using sublime with it or a website called glitch.com

My question is, how can I loop through displaying one shader to the next shader? Here is the javascript file that I have so far. I know I'll need to make a loop with the function draw and call on the two different shaders I preloaded, but am having some trouble with syntax since I am very new to coding. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
let theShader;

function preload(){
  // load the shader
  theShader1 = loadShader('shader1.vert', 'shader1.frag');
  theShader2 = loadShader('shader2.vert', 'shader2.frag');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  noStroke();
}

function draw() {  
  //sets the active shader with shader1
  shader(theShader1);
  
  theShader1.setUniform("iResolution", [width, height]);
  theShader1.setUniform("iFrame", frameCount);
  theShader1.setUniform("iMouse", [mouseX, map(mouseY, 0, height, height, 0)]);


  // rect gives us some geometry on the screen
  rect(0,0,width, height);
}

function windowResized(){
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `theShader1` in draw. Use `theShader` and then based on something (a timer, a count, the user clicking something) set `theShader` to either `theShader1` or `theShader2`

```
    let theShader;
    let oldTime;

    function preload(){
      // load the shader
      theShader1 = loadShader('shader1.vert', 'shader1.frag');
      theShader2 = loadShader('shader2.vert', 'shader2.frag');
      theShader = theShader1;  // start with theShader1
    }

    function setup() {
      createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
      noStroke();
    }

    function draw() {  
      // switch shaders every second
      let time = performance.now() / 1000 | 0;  // convert to seconds
      if (oldTime !== time) {
        oldTime = time;
        theShader = theShader === theShader1 ? theShader2 : theShader1;
      }

      //sets the active shader
      shader(theShader);

      theShader.setUniform("iResolution", [width, height]);
      theShader.setUniform("iFrame", frameCount);
      theShader.setUniform("iMouse", [mouseX, map(mouseY, 0, height, height, 0)]);

      // rect gives us some geometry on the screen
      rect(0,0,width, height);
    }

    function windowResized(){
      resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    }
```

If you have more then 2 shaders put them in an array and keep an index. for example

```
    let theShader;
    let oldTime;
    let shaderNdx = 0;

    const shaders = [];

    function preload(){
      // load the shader
      shaders.push(loadShader('shader1.vert', 'shader1.frag'));
      shaders.push(loadShader('shader2.vert', 'shader2.frag'));
      shaders.push(loadShader('shader3.vert', 'shader3.frag'));
      theShader = shaders[0];  // start with the first shader
    }

    function setup() {
      createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
      noStroke();
    }

    function draw() {  
      // switch shaders every second
      let time = performance.now() / 1000 | 0;  // convert to seconds
      if (oldTime !== time) {
        oldTime = time;
        // increment shader index to the next shader but wrap around 
        // back to 0 at then of the array of shaders
        shaderNdx = (shaderNdx + 1) % shaders.length;
        theShader = shaders[shaderNdx]
      }

      //sets the active shader
      shader(theShader);

      theShader.setUniform("iResolution", [width, height]);
      theShader.setUniform("iFrame", frameCount);
      theShader.setUniform("iMouse", [mouseX, map(mouseY, 0, height, height, 0)]);

      // rect gives us some geometry on the screen
      rect(0,0,width, height);
    }

    function windowResized(){
      resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot!!

Comment: And one follow-up. Say if I want to fade between the shaders. How would exactly would I do that? Can I treat the shaders as an object to fade? I am thinking that the tint() function could be used?